# How to force Windows to use regular/italic versions of a font correctly?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, fonts

I hope this is an appropriate place to ask this question.

I have downloaded the OTF font [Celestia Antiqua Std Regular](https://fontsgeek.com/fonts/Celestia-Antiqua-Std-Regular) and its corresponding [Italic](https://fontsgeek.com/fonts/Celestia-Antiqua-Std-Italic) version.

If I install only the Regular version, I can use it in programs like Word as expected. But if I install both the Regular and Italic versions, then programs like Word use only the Italic version of the font. Note: Word believes the text to be regular/non-italic, but it displays using the Italic version of the font only.

I suspect (but am not sure) that the Italic version of the font in some way specifies that it is Regular, so is being chosen for display when it should not be.

I have tried using FontForge to change the font's Weight to Italic, and exporting as TTF, but this doesn't solve the problem (as well as Font Forge raising a lot of warnings); I don't know much about FontForge so not sure what else to try, besides, it seems like the wrong avenue to go down.

For now, I can get by with installing the Regular version of the font only, but it is not ideal as italic text is only angled, rather than properly italicised. I'd rather install both and Windows/Word/etc. use them as intended, if only this would work.

How can I convince Windows/Word to use the Regular and Italic versions of these fonts appropriately?

Comment: I have the exact same question :(

Comment: I want to add that after reading this section on Name versus subtype I was able to solve the problem. The font name needs to the same for Windows to use the regular and italic. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/recom#name-strings

Answer (score 0):

The font name needs to be the same, only the font subtype should show the italic. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/recom#name-strings

I was using the font Le Monde Livre Book ( https://typofonderie.com/fonts/le-monde-livre-family/ ) and when I purchased the Regular I bought the Pro package, but when I bought the Italic I bought the Standard (STD) package, and "Pro" and "Std" were in the font name. I ended up also buying the Italic Pro package, and the font name was "Le Monde Livre Pro Book" for both Regular and Italic and once I installed the Italic on my computer, MS Word immediately recognized it, and switching from Regular to Italic with ctrl-i worked perfectly.

I hope you resolved your issue in 2021, but I wanted to write this to help whoever has the same problem!